# Highcharts column point positioned in the center

Tags: highcharts

I have column chart with two series.
I need to remove one point from the first series
and I need positioned in the center point in the second series.

For example, I set "Apr" value for Tokyo to null and I need positioned in the center "Apr" value for New York. Is it possible? Thank you.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: null  
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis:{
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May'
            ],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: 14 
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis:  {
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
         legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            floating: false,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
         plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: false,
                    rotation: 270,
                    align: 'left',
                    y: -5,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: 'black' 
                    }
                }
            }
        },
         credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, null, 144.0]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0]

        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PrZK6/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use translate() function which allows to move svg elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/PrZK6/3/

```
chart.series[1].points[3].graphic.translate(-10,0);
```